# "Autoscroll" Pdfs one by one from a "play-list"/directory

Tags: linux, pdf, powershell, shell-script, pdf-reader

Is there a way to achieve this:

open multiple .pdf from a "playlist"/given directory one by one in the same window, with auto-scrolling enabled? 
(Explanation: 1st pdf opens- autoscrolls to the end- 2nd pdf opens-autoscrolls to the end and so on)

*Additional Hint: Think of it like a media player. You load an mp3 playlist and the player plays one file after the other till the list is exhausted.*

OS: Linux Based (preferred)/ Windows (can switch to for this project)